# how can we call a method using jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, session

How can we call a method using jquery? I have a button Logout. I want when anyone click that button the session is destroyed? Means  after a logout button is clicked I want to call the `session.invalidates ()` method..

Comment: Using ajax: `$.post("http://yoursite.com/yourScript");`

Comment: @ASHISH you can instead create a page having session.invalidate() then call that page using jquery

Comment: @javaBeginner ok but if I create a page how can I call that page

Comment: @ASHISH using simple html tag <a href="jsp page">

Comment: @javaBeginner But in that case I have to pass session attribute to that page also. I do not want to do that. I want to destroy the session in the same page.

Comment: @ASHISH no need of passing session attribute.just session.invalidate(); You have mentioned in your question that by using jquery you wanted to do.So i am not posting answer.If you change it then i will post my answer how to do

Comment: @javaBeginner yes, It is working. we don't need to pass session attribute.

Comment: @ASHISH see my answer,hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Two commonly used methods for a request-response between a client and server are: GET and POST.

- GET - Requests data from a specified resource
- POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

**[GET](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)** is basically used for just getting (retrieving) some data from the server. Note: The GET method may return cached data.

code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
});
```

**[POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** can also be used to get some data from the server. However, the POST method NEVER caches data, and is often used to send data along with the request.

Code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: success,
   dataType: dataType
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include your logout button inside a form. Its action will be a Servlet and you can invalidate the session inside the Servlet.

You can of course add a new route inside your server that will handle the session invalidation and you will use jQuery to send the request to that route, but the first solution seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

as session is a server-side method you need to call it via ajax

```
$.ajax({
...
});
```

check to ajax
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and this to bind the click event:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<a href="your_jsp_page">
```

and in your logout.jsp page

```
<%session.invalidate()%>
```

write the above line